# Web Page is automatically reloading several times during automation in selenium using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

[image: This is code's snippet. Function works well for others, so can't see a problem with this, at least.]There comes a junction in my script when a web page automatically reloads several times after clicking one link. What I see during that time on the console in eclipse that it hasn't really clicked on that link though.

The script gets stuck and I can't proceed with my test case. I'm doing nothing extra for this thing, have automated several test cases using the very same function but what do I know about selenium, it decides to not work for this very test case out of nowhere. Could anyone please help me out? I've a deadline to handle.

Can't attach images but could only type in this object's description for you guys,

```
< a target="_self" href="/units/HR/HelpDesk/Pages/HDRequest.aspx" > Raise Query < /a>
```

I use linkText (Raise Query) as my identifier for the same.

Comment: Are there spaces around the "Raise Query"? You can format as code in your question and show _exactly_ what is inside the tag. Which version of Selenium are you using and which language are you writing your tests in?

Comment: No spaces. Fun Fact: I've actually automated the same thing once and it worked but no wins now. Eclipse version: Kepler Service Release 2. Selenium version: 2.42.0. Language used is Java.

Comment: You are using `target` as `_self`. It open the window in same page. Are you sure the page you are refering to is the different page than the one in `href` attribute?

Comment: @nitinchawda : Am not using target. That was just the element's description which I see. am using linkText-  Raise Query. It does open in the same window and keeps on opening/refreshing several infinite times. Its that same page though.

Comment: Can you show us what selenium script snippet/code you tried?

Comment: Edited with code's image. Help me Please!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an internet explorer option thing! I just needed to add my concerned site into their allowance and it got resolved. Than

Answer (score 0):

HI try and work around something more like a FluentWait that polls for each link before rendering ElementNotFound Exception, here's a guide snippet to work around your problem

public String clickLinkbyText(WebDriver driver, final String link){

```
  Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
          .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);


   List<WebElement> element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, List<WebElement>>() {
     public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElements(By.id(link));
     }
   });

  if(element.size()==0) {
  return "No link" +link;

  }

  else if (element.size()>1){

      return "";
  }
  else{

      element.get(0).click();
      return "Passed";

  }
}

}
```